# Undo/Redo for AppState in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm creating an app with rust and require undo/redo functionality. The [undo crate](https://crates.io/crates/undo) seems like
it offers some nice functionality to do this, but I can figure out how to apply the simple example
to a more complex setup, where `AppState` is stored inside of a RefCell inside of `AppContainer`. When AppContainer
mutates AppState, I want to be able to undo/redo that mutation.

Here I tried to implement this, but I don't think this is the correct route. For one `apply()` expects a mutable reference, but
I dont know how to both mutate the container and send the data that needed for the mutation.

So what would be a correct way of mutating the state while enabling undo/redo?

What I've provided here is just a general sense of how I imagine this being structured:

```rust
use undo::{Action, History};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

//this is my app states, containing all the state data
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct AppState{
    names: Vec<String>
    //...
}

//App container provides interior mutability
struct AppContainer(Rc<RefCell<AppState>>);

//various functions for mutating AppState, each of which I would like to be able to undo/redo 
impl AppContainer{
    fn new (inner: AppState)->AppContainer{
        let cl = AppState{
            names: inner.names.clone(),
        };
        return AppContainer(Rc::new(RefCell::new(cl)));
    }
    fn add_name(&self, name: String){
        (self.0.borrow_mut()).names.push(name);
    }
    fn remove_name(&self, to_remove: String){
        (self.0.borrow_mut()).names.retain(|x| *x != to_remove)
    }
    fn names(&self)->Vec<String>{
        (self.0.borrow()).names
    }
}

//Action for adding a name
struct AddName(String);
impl Action for AddName{
    type Target = (String, AppContainer);
    type Output = ();
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn apply(&mut self, s: (String, &mut AppContainer)) -> undo::Result<AddName> {
        s.1.add_name(s.0);
        Ok(())
    }

    fn undo(&mut self, s: (String, &mut AppContainer)) -> undo::Result<AddName> {
        s.1.remove_name(s.0);
        Ok(())
    }
    
}
//Action for removing a name
struct RemoveName(String);
impl Action for RemoveName{
    type Target = (String, AppContainer);
    type Output = ();
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn apply(&mut self, s: (String, &mut AppContainer)) -> undo::Result<RemoveName> {
        s.1.remove_name(s.0);
        Ok(())
    }

    fn undo(&mut self, s: (String, &mut AppContainer)) -> undo::Result<RemoveName> {
        s.1.add_name(s.0);
        Ok(())
    }
    
}


fn main(){
    type Target = (String, AppContainer);
    type Output = ();
    type Error = &'static str;

    let initial_state = AppState{
        names: vec!["name 1".to_string(), "name 2".to_string()],
    };
    let mut history = History::new();
    let mut container = AppContainer::new(initial_state.clone());
    history.apply(&mut container, AddName("My Name".to_string())).unwrap();
    dbg!(container.names());
    history.apply(&mut container, RemoveName("Name 1".to_string())).unwrap();
    dbg!(container.names());
    //Errors becuase apply expects a mutable reference, not a tuple
}
```

[Example from the undo repo:](https://github.com/evenorog/undo)

```rust
use undo::{Action, History};

struct Add(char);

impl Action for Add {
    type Target = String;
    type Output = ();
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn apply(&mut self, s: &mut String) -> undo::Result<Add> {
        s.push(self.0);
        Ok(())
    }

    fn undo(&mut self, s: &mut String) -> undo::Result<Add> {
        self.0 = s.pop().ok_or("s is empty")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() -> undo::Result<Add> {
    let mut target = String::new();
    let mut history = History::new();
    history.apply(&mut target, Add('a'))?;
    history.apply(&mut target, Add('b'))?;
    history.apply(&mut target, Add('c'))?;
    assert_eq!(target, "abc");
    history.undo(&mut target)?;
    history.undo(&mut target)?;
    history.undo(&mut target)?;
    assert_eq!(target, "");
    history.redo(&mut target)?;
    history.redo(&mut target)?;
    history.redo(&mut target)?;
    assert_eq!(target, "abc");
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: You haven't declared `container` as mutable.